# Flutter Google map fix my marker but rotate the map on moving

Tags: flutter, routes, maps

Hello everyone i'm stuck in something it seems really simple
i just built flutter app based on google maps all i need to do is when i move i want to FIX the marker but rotate the map according to the route and the route being vertically forced always
i have tried bearing and tilting but its not working as good as i expected
in other word i need exact same thing like the real google maps app when we moving
thank you
i just did everything correctly but target moving and map not rotating automatically according to the route

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this feature should be out of box, but it's not. It seems the only way you can do this is to use bearing. It will not work the same way as google maps markers are (there is a delay before rotation), but it still looks fine.

I use following approach to not re render a lot of markers to often (with redux it is a little bit easier):

```
GoogleMap(
    onCameraMove: (CameraPosition position) {
      setState(() { // or via any state management tool
        _cameraBearing = position.bearing;
      });
    },
    onCameraMoveStarted: () {
      setState(() {
        _previousCameraBearing = _cameraBearing;
      });
    },
    onCameraIdle: () {
      if (_cameraBearing != _previousCameraBearing) {
        // update your markers
      }
    },
    ...
)
```